# multithread or multiprocess to control subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

When using `ThreadPoolExecutor` vs `ProcessPoolExcecutor` it is a clear choice when all code is written in python.

But what should be used when python uses the subprocess module to kick off task that require heavy compute?

For example I use subprocess to kick off a program that uses NIM, or C++, Does python see that as IO since it is not outside of its language?

Comment: you don't need to worry about the GIL in case that's what you're wondering. It's a totally separate process as far as the OS is concerned. I guess I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Does python see that as IO since it is not outside of its language?"

Comment: The only relationship between the parent process (python in this case) and the child process (whatever you called from subprocess) could be (based on configuration, OS, and a few other things) a few pipes for stdio, stdin, stdout to the child, and signals sent to the parent might also get sent to the child (ie: sigterm). They share nothing else unless specifically designed to do so.